# android webview interactive chart (draggable)

Tags: android, html, charts, android-webview

I wanted to create a chart in webview that allows the user to click and drag accordingly based on the user. I looked into a few library like RGraph and aChartEngine, those library can only create a chart which the user could not customize the data. Is there any library or other ways that I can create a chart that user can customize the data?

Comment: There are many meanings of "customizing the data". What do you mean by that?

Comment: For example: something like this, user can change customize the data on real-time. http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/customHighlighterCursorTrendline.html